# Can I implement a server-side rendered svelte component in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

We can write server code for pages such as
`+page.svelte`
`+page.ts`
`+page.server.ts`
But can we apply the same approach to non-page components, such as
`component.ts` for `component.svelte` ?

I am looking for a solution to render components on the server-side without taking arguments. For example, a weather widget has no connection to the page where it is located.

Comment: Components do not have a route, so you cannot refer them directly. You need to wrap them to a route/page first. Then you can call this route, render the HTML snippet on the server side and use `@html` directivity to inject the raw HTML in the parent component.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa you say: *`call this route, render the HTML snippet on the server side and use @html directivity to inject the raw HTML in the parent component`*. So you would make a `routes/partials/weather/+page.server.js` etc. and then? How can you render this inside a component? Could you please post an answer with pseudo-code for this?

Comment: If you have a question please use Ask Question button to open a new w question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Hi, sure I could, but it'd be practically the same question as this one. I just didn't quite understand (part of) your proposed solution. Would you consider posting an answer, instead of a comment if you have the time? Cheers